# Add back arrow in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I have this code which creates a UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle: @"ToDo"
                               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self action: @selector(popToRoot:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

The issue is that removes the left arrow, and I would like to include that next to the text. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: create image of backbutton and use image...

Comment: How would I accomplish that?

Comment: I hope on back button you will have same text... right? on you will have custom text?

Comment: The text will always be "ToDo", as stated in the code above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBtn.png"]  ;  
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 30);  
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;  
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

then define goback method like this

```
- (void)goback
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note: BackBtn.png will have ToDo text and back button image...

### Another way

If you want to do without image, then add below code...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
    self.title = @"Your Title"
}

-(void)viewWillDissapear {
    self.title = @"ToDo"
}
```

this will create ToDo when you goes to next view...

Comment: I get nothing when I try your code. No button at all?

Comment: This is gonna sound daft, how do I add the image? Shouldn't it already be there by default cause it is standard in iphone apps?

Comment: its standard... but you need to create image of what you are looking for... there is another way, but its ugly way...

Comment: @PeterStuart : did you tried another way? is it working?

Comment: what you get at back button? while trying second way, please remove code you have in my first way... even remove your code also...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48623/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-peter-stuart)